# VueJS i18n Routes 404 Page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-i18n

## The Idea

Let me first tell you the idea, user enter "domain.com" user will get redirected to "domain.com/en" where is set by default to the english language, after that user can navigate throughout the website for example to "domain.com/en/about-us/".

## My Issue

I can't figure out how to set up the routing for the "domain.com/wrong-page" where is also the global i18n parameter that i'm waiting for or "domain.com/wrong-language/corect-page" so the user can get the appropriate 404 page that i want.

## My Set Up

#### Router file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import i18n from '../i18n'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: `/${i18n.locale}`
  },
  {
    path: '/:lang',
    component: {
      render(c) { return c('router-view') }
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        name: 'About',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/*',
        name: '404',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "404" */ '../components/404.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})


export default router
```

#### Main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import i18n from './i18n'

import LanguageSwitcher from "@/components/LanguageSwitcher.vue";
import NavigationTopMenu from "./components/NavigationTopMenu.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";

Vue.component('language-switcher', LanguageSwitcher)
Vue.component('navigation-top-menu', NavigationTopMenu)
Vue.component('footer-g', Footer)


Vue.config.productionTip = false

// use beforeEach route guard to set the language
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // use the language from the routing param or default language
  let language = to.params.lang;
  if (!language) {
    language = 'en'
  }

  // set the current language for i18n.
  i18n.locale = language
  next()
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

So, another developer reached out to me, the answer was pretty straight forward we can implement a custom regex for the lang to limit what can be matched with.

```
:lang
```

needs to be

```
:lang(en|fr|es)
```

another solution is to configure the navigation guard further and redirect to the following error page.